# PARTITION BY 2 columns

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to make a partition but I seem to be blind about one simple thing.

Let's say I have two columns `ProductID` and `ProductName` where sometimes `ProductID` has remained the same and `ProductName` has changed.

Or two or more Products with different `ProductID` has the same name.

How can I make a PARTITION BY statement consider them the same?

```
ProductID      ProductName    Price
001             Product1      5
001             Product2      4
005             Product1      3

AVG(Price) OVER (PARTITION BY ProductID, ProductName) ?????

Desired OUTPUT >>> AVERAGE PRICE 4
```

Comment: just use `PARTITION BY ProductID` then?

Comment: It will not consider then case when two products with different ProductID has the same names

Comment: Not sure what you mean. You state you want all names to be the same but then you want them different. How about some sample data and desired output. I am not at all getting what you are trying to do here.

Comment: there you go...

Comment: Your output doesn't make a lot of sense here. Why is ProductID 001 and 005 the same thing? Seems there is something lacking in your data if you need something like this.

Comment: i'd recommend sorting your data out, this seems like an issue before your query. if the data can get in such a state then something is causing the problem you are trying to deal with.

Comment: You need to decide your rule. If your it is considering all products with the same ID as one product or the same description.

Comment: It is made this way becouse over the time, the ProductName may have changed to make it more descriptive or the Product had minor changes.

OR lets say we have two bottles of wine, each with different ProductID but they are similar enough to have the same ProductName

Sometimes the maker decides to change the ProductID

Comment: Different bottles of wine are not the same thing though. You need to determine how to group these. As you have it the logic is too sloppy. You would need a recursive cte to traverse both ProductID and Names to see which ones might kind of sort be the "same". You essentially have a many to many relationship within the same table across two columns.

Comment: Sometimes the maker just decides to change ProductID without an apparent reason.

Comment: Well given the horrific state of this data you can't use partitioning on any of the existing columns. You are going to have to determine which products belong to each other. As I said before you will need multiple recursive ctes to figure this out accurately. First get all ProductIDs and then all Names for each "Product". You are going to need to provide more details about your data here to be able to help.

Comment: Figured out that i can just use the latest ProductName since Name changes trough time are not so relevant and then just Partition over the names.

I guess talking the things out can clarify some ideas. Thanks to everyone.